# signal.connect(self) UnicodeEncodeError:

Tags: python, pyqt5

What is wrong with `self.ao.ownSignal.connect(self.on_сliked)`? The program worked once, but there was an error the second time I ran it.

Here is the whole code (I'm trying to create some GUI for my application):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class AnyObject(QObject):
    #create out own signal
    ownSignal = pyqtSignal()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()


    self.initUserInterface()

# event which trigger when mouse clicked in window
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    # generate signal
    self.ao.ownSignal.emit()
    self.close()

def initUserInterface(self):

    self.ao = AnyObject()
    # signal handler
    self.ao.ownSignal.connect(self.on_сliked)

    # main window parameters
    self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1200, 800)
    self.setWindowTitle('5G Simulator')
    self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('images/5Glogo.jpg'))

    self.show()

def on_сliked(self):
    print("IT IS CLICKED")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    backgroundWindow = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/User/Google Drive/Dev/Python/PyCharmProjects/scheduler5G/MainWindow.py", line 53, in <module>
backgroundWindow = MainWindow()
File "C:/Users/User/Google Drive/Dev/Python/PyCharmProjects/scheduler5G/MainWindow.py", line 25, in __init__
self.initUserInterface()
File "C:/Users/User/Google Drive/Dev/Python/PyCharmProjects/scheduler5G/MainWindow.py", line 37, in initUserInterface
self.ao.ownSignal.connect(self.on_сliked)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0441' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: What is  AnyObject?

Comment: Just editted it.

Comment: Please also add the traceback to your error.

Comment: Are you compiling your pythoncode to .pyc?

Comment: not, it is *.py

Comment: @RuslanV.Akhpashev you should be more careful when typing with cyrillic keyboard layouts, only ASCII characters are allowed for object names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Are you *sure* you've posted exactly the source code you're using?</del>

After all, that `\u0441` referenced is [CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ES](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0441/index.htm), which does not seem to appear in your code...

It apparently is the same code!

That said, since you're running on Windows, that error often stems from attempting to print out certain Unicode characters to the Windows console, which can be a little dumb about things. Running `chcp 65001` to make the console UTF-8 might make things better, or worse; `SET PYTHONIOENCODING=mbcs:replace` might also help but make unprintable characters question marks.

**EDIT:** However, the problem here is that qt signals contain some stringly typed bits – your signal handler's name can not apparently contain non-ASCII characters such as that cyrillic `с` in `on_сliked`, even if Python allows them.

Comment: @AKX yes, it does, it's the "с" in "on_сliked", which is not a real c, but the cyrillic character that looks like it.